# Google Apps Script Regexes: Difficulty matching parentheses with contents

Tags: regex, google-apps-script, escaping

I'm building a custom function for a spreadsheet in Google Apps Script, and have run into a snag.

What I need to do is take the contents of a cell and replace an entry of "0" with "5", and remove "(immobile)" if present (and it might not always be present), leaving everything else intact.  The cell contents could look like any of the following:
"0 ft. (immobile)"
"0 ft."
"0 ft., fly 20 ft."
"0 ft. (immobile), fly 20 ft."

The 0 ft will always be at beginning of the input, and the (immobile), if present, will always be the next non-white-space.

I've built several regexes, and I cannot get it match a group of just "(immobile)". To simplify things, I'm currently just trying to match and capture, without replacing, but having fits with that, as well. Here's what I've got so far:

```
function getPlantSpeed(plantSpeed){
  var mySpeedRE = /^(0)( ft\..*?)(\(immobile\))?(.*)$/i;
  var testCaptures = mySpeedRE.exec(plantSpeed);
  return testCaptures;
} 
getPlantSpeed("0 ft. (immobile)"); 
getPlantSpeed("0 ft., swim 30 ft."); 
getPlantSpeed("0 ft. (immobile), swim 30 ft.");
```

The captures for each of these end up looking like:
"0 ft. (immobile", "0", "ft.", undefined, " (immobile)"
"0 ft., swim 30 ft.", "0", "ft.", undefined, " swim 30 ft."
and
"0 ft. (immobile), swim 30 ft.", "0", "ft.", undefined, "(immobile), swim 30 ft."

respectively.

I've tried changing the ? after the attempted match for (immobile) to {0,1} and *, respectively, without any changes. I cannot seem to match "(immobile)" on its own.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Seems to be working fine to me..  Here's a jsfiddle of it - http://jsfiddle.net/7KWKz/

Comment: I can't get it to do anything at jsfiddle at all... but I may just be a bit slow in that regard.

Comment: You have to view the output of the jsfiddle in your browser console. Do you know how to open the console in your browser?  Every browser is a little different but it would be in something like 'Tools` or `Developer Tools` or even `Javascript Console` or something like that.

Comment: Got it, thought it would show up in the "result" pain in JSFiddle, but once I opened the browser console, I found the output. It's broken,there, too. The way the regex is written, the "undefined" **should** be (immobile), if it's present.

`["0 ft. (immobile)", "0", " ft.", undefined, " (immobile)", index: 0, input: "0 ft. (immobile)"] (index):26
["0 ft., swim 30 ft.", "0", " ft.", undefined, ", swim 30 ft.", index: 0, input: "0 ft., swim 30 ft."] (index):27
["0 ft. (immobile), swim 30 ft.", "0", " ft.", undefined, " (immobile), swim 30 ft.", index: 0, input: "0 ft. (immobile), swim 30 ft."] `

Comment: To simplify things, it's easier to see this code failing:
`function getPlantSpeed(plantSpeed){
  var mySpeedRE = /(\(immobile\))?/i;
  var testCaptures = mySpeedRE.exec(plantSpeed);
  return testCaptures;
} 
console.log(getPlantSpeed("0 ft. (immobile)")); 
console.log(getPlantSpeed("0 ft., swim 30 ft.")); 
console.log(getPlantSpeed("0 ft. (immobile), swim 30 ft."));`

Comment: thanks for your comments.  helps troubleshooting. I supplied an answer. The main problem with your last regex, was that you had 4 capturing groups, so you were getting 4 captures, and where there was not a match, you were getting 'undefined' because you were still capturing it.  Note my answer has 3 capturing groups with an OR operator(|) in the last group.  Hope my answer helps!  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, how about this:

```
/^(0)( ft\.).*?(\(immobile\)|.*)$/i
```

Here working regex example:

http://regex101.com/r/iS6zD3

And here's working jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/7KWKz/1/

The main problem with your last regex, was that you had 4 capturing groups, so you were getting 4 captures, and where there was not a match, you were getting 'undefined' because you were still capturing it.

Note my answer has 3 capturing groups with an OR operator(|) in the last group.

To simplify, I'm not sure why you couldn't just do this:

```
/^(0)( ft\.)(.*)$/i
```

It returns the same results.

Hope this helps!

---

**EDIT:** *After reading OP's comments, I realize I misunderstood his question...*

Ok, here's javascript doing exactly what is asked:

Quote -  `"replace an entry of "0" with "5", and remove "(immobile)" if present (and it might not always be present), leaving everything else intact."`

Javascript:

```
function getPlantSpeed(plantSpeed){
  var mySpeedRE = /^(0)\s(ft\.)[\s]*(\(immobile\))?(,.*)?$/i;
  var replce = plantSpeed.replace(mySpeedRE, "5 $2$4");
  return replce;
} 
console.log(getPlantSpeed("0 ft. (immobile)")); 
console.log(getPlantSpeed("0 ft., swim 30 ft.")); 
console.log(getPlantSpeed("0 ft. (immobile), swim 30 ft."));
console.log(getPlantSpeed("0 ft."));
```

Output:

```
5 ft.
5 ft., swim 30 ft.
5 ft., swim 30 ft.
5 ft.
```

jsfiddle example:

http://jsfiddle.net/7KWKz/2/

Comment: I posted a response that disappeared. Thanks for all the help. Your example on regex101 actually shows why your suggestion using alternation won't work in my case. The third example line matches (immobile) in the same capture as everything that comes after it. I need to match (immobile) by itself, in its own capture, if it's there, regardless of what is around it, and I can't seem to. Here's a regex101 link with the simplest version of the bit that is giving me problems. As soon as I add a quantifier, even a greedy one, it stops matching or capturing. [link](http://regex101.com/r/iF0dY6)

Comment: Ok, thank you, I think I understand, first of all, concerning your link just provided, the only problem with it is you are not capturing you quantifier..  It should be..  `(\(immobile\)?)` - notice the `?` is Inside the capturing parenthesis. Here's the [link](http://regex101.com/r/tX5kV4) to an updated regex101 showing this.. So now I'm going to Modify/Edit my answer to satisfy what it is that you are trying to achieve. :)

Comment: @Hirsute - I added an **Edit** to my answer..  I think, I hope it is the solution for exactly what you are trying to do..  If not, let me know. If so, please accept as answer or upvote or both.  thx.  :)

Comment: I couldn't up vote or select as an answer the comment that has the working solution in it, so I did both to the parent comment. The last revision seems to do exactly what I need it to. Thanks again! Edit:I don't have enough rep to up vote, but I did accept as answer, thanks!